# Joomla - using the same menu for header and footer, but showing extra link in the footer...?

Tags: joomla, joomla-template, joomla1.7

I'm trying to setup a website menu in Joomla 1.7 but I'm having difficulty because I can't add `home` link twice. It says something like 'alias is already used', or another weird error. I created two menus: one called `main menu` other called `footer menu`. I'm adding like 6 pages as `single article`.

I'm guessing I have to use `main menu` twice, and just load it into two different menu modules: one for main menu, one for footer. The thing is, the footer menu has 1 more link than the main menu. Is there a way I can add a link to main menu, use the main menu for both main/footer menu modules, but only have that extra link appear in the footer module?

Really stuck here, need your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the *second menu* (and the corresponding module) for the footer
with Menu Item Types **Menu Item Alias** associated with *first menu* items
and add to the *second menu* one more item of the requested type.

Comment: Thank You! You are a wizard, and that was some awesome black magic.